# How to convert a long date to short date from SSL certificates | Unix KSH

Tags: date, datetime, unix, converters, date-formatting

I'm wondering if is possible to convert a date as show `Oct 31 00:00:00 2013 GMT` to `10-31-2013`.

I'm getting the date as follow:

```
NotBeforeDate=$(openssl x509 -noout -in ${CERTIFICATE} -dates | grep "notBefore")
```

The date that I'm getting is `Oct 31 00:00:00 2013 GMT` and I wanted to convert it to `10-31-2013`.

There's any command that could do that? Or do I have to do it all manually?

If so, the best way is create my own function and send the long date as parameter and return a short date.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more...is that date coming from a `log` file or something?

Comment: @Hackerman I get that date from SSL certificate and is saved in a variable, just wondering if it could be converted to short date.

Comment: `saved in a variable`, how?

Comment: using the following command:
`NotBeforeDate=$(openssl x509 -noout -in ${CERTIFICATE} -dates | grep "notBefore")`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The openssl command will make the `NotBeforeDate` variable to have the value (at least in the bash version I'm using):

```
notBefore=Oct 31 00:00:00 2013 GMT
```

So, first we need to remove the `notBefore=` part:

```
dateStr=${NotBeforeDate/notBefore=/}
```

Then you can use the `date` command:

```
date --date="$dateStr" --utc +"%m-%d-%Y"
```

The `--date` option tells the command to use the `dateStr` value, `--utc` tells that the date is in UTC (as specified by `GMT` part) and `+"%m-%d-%Y"` formats the date to the desired format.

The output is:

> 10-31-2013

---

**PS:** the options can vary according to your Linux version.
You can check all the available ones with `date --help` or `man date`.

For example, the long options `--date` and `--utc` might not be available, but the equivalent short versions might be (just an example, I'm not sure if `date` command has such variations between different unix versions):

```
date -d "$dateStr" -u +"%m-%d-%Y"
```

Unfortunately I don't have the exact same environment you're using (ksh in unix), but that should work.

---

The  `-d` options seems to be GNU specific, so if it's not available, you'll have to manually parse the string. Assuming that `dateStr` has the value `Oct 31 00:00:00 2013 GMT`, you can run:

```
printf '%s\n' "$dateStr" | awk '{ printf "%02d-%02d-%04d\n", (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$1)+2)/3, $2, $4}'
```

The output is:

> 10-31-2013

Comment: I tried that but I think date version is old, message displayed: `date: illegal option`

Comment: @JavierSalas Have you tried both (`--date` and `-d`)? What options it shows if you type `date --help`?

Comment: it doesn't work as well, it is using the legacy mode

Comment: @JavierSalas If the `-d` option is not available, you'll have to parse the string - I've updated my answer with a solution using `awk`

Answer (score 2):

This script works for me when checking a url with certificate.

```
date --date="$(echo | openssl s_client -servername $DOMAIN -connect $DOMAIN:$PORT | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | awk -F '=' '{print $NF}' )" --iso-8601
```

PORT is 443 by default.

Comment: Output only date
`date --date="$(echo | openssl s_client -servername $DOMAIN -connect $DOMAIN:443 2 > /dev/null| openssl x509 -noout -enddate | awk -F '=' '{print $NF}' )" --iso-8601`

Answer (score 1):

In new version of openssl this option is build in:

```
openssl x509 -noout -in ${CERTIFICATE} -enddate -dateopt iso_8601
notBefore=2021-04-15 09:23:07Z
```

It returns date and time, however cutting the time part should be no challenge.

And it looks like, you really need the most recent version of openssl: [--dateopt option does not work](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/18553)

Answer (score 0):

Not to duplicate the explanations for the `date` command in previous answers, here's a compact Bash function that reads a certificate file and outputs either the start or end date in either ISO format or as a Unix timestamp (useful for integer comparison), and can be used on Linux or macOS:

```sh
# cert_date <date_type> <out_format> <cert_file> [openssl_opts...]
#  date_type: start|end
# out_format: iso|unix
cert_date() {
  local type=$1 out=$2 args date opts fmt
  [ "$type" == start ] && args=(-startdate) || args=(-enddate)
  date=$(openssl x509 "${args[@]}" -noout -in "${@:3}")
  [[ "$OSTYPE" == darwin* ]] && opts=(-juf "%b %d %T %Y %Z") || opts=(-ud)
  [ "$out" == unix ] && fmt="%s" || fmt="%Y-%m-%dT%TZ"
  date "${opts[@]}" "${date/*=/}" +"$fmt"
}
```

Of course, you can enhance by changing `fmt` to suit your output format needs, and even add a case statement to accept more formats.

Examples:

```sh
cert_date start iso  ${CERTIFICATE}
cert_date end   unix ${CERTIFICATE} -inform der
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a bash OneLiner from the ideas above. Maybe it is useful for somebody:

(Use 'cut -c 10-' when greeping notAfter)

```
date -d "`openssl x509 -dates -noout -in /path/to/cert.pem | grep notBefore | cut -c 11-`" +%Y.%m.%d
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I search how to convert date and especially the end date. And inspired by the command lines posted here I made this one :

```
date --date="$(echo | openssl x509 -noout -in my_file.crt -enddate | cut -d'=' -f 2)" --utc +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Cutting is easier because as I only want the end date, I use the "**enddate**" parameter of the openssl command